# Finding unknown concentration using HPLC standard curve

Tags: analytical-chemistry, concentration, chromatography

I calculated a standard curve equation from a given concentration and peak area, which gave me $y=1994.6x+218.4$. I made the graph with the $x$-axis μg/mL and $y$-axis peak area.

The question is, a sample of $\pu{20.00 mL}$ containing a food with the analyte had $5123$ peak area. Can I just plug in the $5123$ into the $y$ and be done, or do I divide the that answer by $\pu{20.00 mL}$?

Comment: Which volume have you injected to get the chromatograms ? Is it always the same ?

Answer (score 3):

Part of your confusion is arising from the fact that you are thinking that concentration is volume dependent. It is *not* because it is an intensive quantity. For example, the concentration of $\ce{NaCl}$ in seawater will be the same, if you were to take a drop of seawater. The difference is the actual amount of the salt. Now that you have the equation, $y=1994.6x+218.4$, plug in the peak area of the unknown and calculate $x$. This is the concentration of your analyte in the (diluted) sample.

No further calculation can be made from the given information. Now if the mass of the food sample were given, you would now use the extra information of $\pu{20 mL}$ for further calculation.

Answer (score 1):

HPLC sample peak areas are usually compared with standard and end standard peak areas to give a percent of unknown analyte **concentration** to Standard concentration.

You then work back through your dilutions to get, in this case, ug/ml of analyte in the original sample preparation flask.

Next you *multiply* by ml of that flask to get ug of analyte.  Then you divide this by sample weight and multiply by 100%.

But before doing any of this, make sure the Chromatography is producing nice sharp peaks and the software is properly integrating the standard and sample peak bases.  This will help avoid considerable error in analysis.

Instead of relying on a computer generated curve, each Chromatogram can be checked.  If Chromatography is good and standard injections are within an acceptable % RSD, then raw peak data can be entered into a spreadsheet.

These spreadsheets can be printed and presented in the analysis report, along with the stack of chromatograms.